# Has anyone studied the properties of the following method of estimation?

Tags: bayesian, references, markov-chain-montecarlo

In Bayesian inference, we usually sample from the posterior $f(\theta_1,\theta_2|-)$ via MCMC to compute point estimates for the parameters of interest. I am investigating an alternate form of arriving at a point estimate. Sometimes it happens that drawing from the full posterior, $f(\theta_1,\theta_2|-)$, is difficult but it is relatively easy to draw from the conditionals $f(\theta_1|\theta_2,-)$ and $f(\theta_2|\theta_1,-)$.

Thus, I want to investigate the properties of the following sampler:

`Initialize` $\theta_1=\theta_1^0$, $\theta_2=\theta_2^0$

```
Converged = False  
Do While Not(Converged)
```

$\quad$ `Set` $\theta_1^i$ = $E(\theta_1|\theta_2^{i-1},-)$
$\quad$ `Set` $\theta_2^i$ = $E(\theta_2|\theta_1^{i-1},-)$
$\quad$ `If` $|\theta_1^i-\theta_1^{i-1}|\le \epsilon$ `and` $|\theta_2^i-\theta_2^{i-1}|\le \epsilon$

```
    Converged = True  
  End If  
End While
```

Some preliminary simulations suggest that the above sampler converges very fast in the context of linear regression. Could someone point me to an existing literature which looks at theoretical properties of the above sampler?

Comment: Well, you said it is different from MCMC practice... I fail to understand how; in my opinion it is exactly what the Gibb's sampler does.

Comment: @Adam It is not the Gibbs sampler. The Gibbs generates a random draw from the conditional density at any given iteration whereas the proposed algorithm computes the expected value from the conditional at any given iteration.

Comment: Oh yes, I misread your post. But then, your method doesn't allow for standard error, just point estimate, right?